# Plug HRV (Constructo 2.0 ES) into power bar?

Tags: electrical, hvac

Would there be any issues if I plugged [this HRV](http://www.venmar.ca/DATA/DOCUMENT/172_3_en~v~Specification_Sheet.pdf) into a power bar? I have this unit  (says 200 watts of power) which is in the closet of the master bedroom and plugged directly into a wall socket.

I want to plug some other things (router, computer, PoE Adapter) in and got a Surge Protector that's rated up to 1800 watts.

Are any issues if I plugged it into the surge protector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by power bar you mean.

[image]

Then, **Yes** you can.

Make sure to wire up your plug correctly and properly. If it did not come originally with a plug then check if the wires are sat firmly within the plug.

> As per you comment. It is possibly true for cheap power blocks with no
>   certification or valuation, so don't use cheap ones for lots of
>   things.  If you are paying a premium price for a power block with
>   surge protection and marked as 1800Watt then you can be pretty sure it
>   passes all tests to handle this wattage. (beware of fakes)

For the second part, Yes you can also plug all your other appliances into the power bar.

You just have to make sure that the total combined wattage does not get excessive. As a guideline I would say stay under 1000watt constant usage.

The 1800watt means the power bar can handle a maximum of 1800watt but it does not mean you should push it to that limit.

Comment: I remember reading somewhere or someone said something about plugging in A/Cs or other large appliances into power bars was a bad idea and could potentially damage the appliance and that they should be plugged directly into the wall socket.  I just wanted to make sure before I do that.

Comment: Nope. I run my 1200Watt Gaming machine with two 6990, i5 processor than run off a power bar. Using a Watt-O-Matt it shows me about 900Watt (when playing games at ridiculous settings,about 500w normal settings, 280Watt desktop and about 200 watt idle) . That is plugged into my power bar that also runs my Microserver (200watt), adsl modem, wifi router, voipgateway, telephones, laser printer and other stuff. I use 1 plug though and that's about MAX for the room. I would NOT add a 1000watt electric heater to that wile playing games.

Comment: Why do you think it will cause any problems? People used to separate things like this from a power bar because of analogue interference caused by the engines and or high power devices that caused feedback. That is no longer a problem now a days as most appliances use good power supplies that filter out the noise but mostly because most data is digital and does not suffer from this "old" phatom. You just cant exceed the maximum wattage rating of the power socket it self and the breaker it is on.

Comment: Nah, I just remember reading somewhere that large appliances could potentially be damaged if using cheap power bars or not plugged directly into a wall.